# Rstudio is painfully slow

Tags: r, rstudio

Suddenly, Rstudio is painfully slow, and now it is unusable. This means, I open it up and there is a lag of several seconds if I type anything. I have explored all the options I can come up with: 
1. re-installing both R and Rstudio (although I am not 100% sure I could remove all components), 
2. trying to reset settings.... the obvious things such as clearing the workspace and the console.

The size of my data is negligible. I cannot think of anything else.... any ideas?

The only observation i can make that shows something could be wrong with the configuration is (sometimes), I see "gctorture false" as a value in the environment.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just a guess, but ?gctorture says

```
 Provokes garbage collection on (nearly) every memory allocation.
 Intended to ferret out memory protection bugs.  Also makes R run
 _very_ slowly, unfortunately.
```

which sounds about right for your problem! You could try

```
gctorture(FALSE)
```

If that speeds things up, then look for somewhere that this might have been set, e.g., in a .Rprofile (current working directory, or your user home directory, or the installation directory of R; see `?.Rprofile`) and make sure that you start R *without* loading any .Rhistory or .RData files (again in the working directory, your home directory, etc.)

Comment: thanks! Possibly, I am good now. I tried previously gctorture(on=FALSE), but to no avail. If this is the problem, I have no idea how it was switched on.

Comment: seems that was it ))

Answer (score 1):

I had a RStudio project with Git Version Control and then it became very slow. I solved the problem by removing the Git Version Control

Comment: This is interesting, I'm wondering if this would happen of you have too many files in the git or too large files/diffs of metadata files such as `.json`. Could you comment if any of these apply in your case?