# R / RStudio Painfully Slow

Tags: r, performance, rstudio, startup

In the past few months, R and RStudio have become almost unusable due to long startup times and performance. The problem has always existed when I would work over my company's VPN; however, it has since become a problem no matter how I connect (without VPN, with VPN, directly to office Ethernet).  I've seen others complain about RStudio running slowly when using a VPN, but this problem exists for both RStudio and the RGui, regardless of my connection.

I found a similar link on StackOverflow ([Rstudio is painfully slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50591476/rstudio-is-painfully-slow)) that was solved by running `gctorture(FALSE)`; however, this has not improved the situation for me. I also researched all of the threads on RStudio Community (the most pertinent being https://community.rstudio.com/t/rstudio-slow-response-over-vpn/6225) but none of the poster's issues seem to match my own.

Some reference points for how slow things are operating: Loading RStudio takes upwards of 5-7 minutes (during which I am staring at a blank white screen), and running `library(tidyverse)` takes 7-10 minutes.  Loading RGui does not take long, but running `library(tidyverse)` again takes between 7-10 minutes.

I'm not sure what other information would be useful to know, but I don't even know how to further investigate this problem on my own. I have tried un/reinstalling R and RStudio. I've tried resetting RStudio's state (https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200534577-Resetting-RStudio-Desktop-s-State). I've tried globally changing my working directory to always reference a local path / folder for R libraries to avoid going over my company's OneDrive network. Nothing has worked.

Running `sessionInfo()` returns:

```
>sessionInfo()
R version 3.5.3 (2019-03-11)
Platform: i386-w64-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 15063)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252 
[2] LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] data.table_1.12.0 forcats_0.3.0     stringr_1.4.0     dplyr_0.8.0.1    
 [5] purrr_0.3.0       readr_1.3.1       tidyr_0.8.2       tibble_2.0.1     
 [9] ggplot2_3.1.0     tidyverse_1.2.1  

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] withr_2.1.2      rvest_0.3.2      tidyselect_0.2.5 lattice_0.20-38 
 [5] pkgconfig_2.0.2  xml2_1.2.0       compiler_3.5.3   readxl_1.2.0    
 [9] Rcpp_1.0.0       cli_1.0.1        plyr_1.8.4       cellranger_1.1.0
[13] httr_1.4.0       tools_3.5.3      nlme_3.1-137     broom_0.5.1     
[17] R6_2.4.0         scales_1.0.0     assertthat_0.2.0 gtable_0.2.0    
[21] stringi_1.3.1    rstudioapi_0.9.0 backports_1.1.3  hms_0.4.2       
[25] munsell_0.5.0    grid_3.5.3       colorspace_1.4-0 glue_1.3.0      
[29] lubridate_1.7.4  rlang_0.3.1      magrittr_1.5     generics_0.0.2  
[33] lazyeval_0.2.1   crayon_1.3.4     haven_2.0.0      modelr_0.1.3    
[37] pillar_1.3.1     jsonlite_1.6
```

and `Sys.getenv()` returns:

```
>Sys.getenv()
ALLUSERSPROFILE         C:\ProgramData
APPDATA                 C:\Users\combsd\AppData\Roaming
CommonProgramFiles      C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files
CommonProgramFiles(x86)
                        C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files
CommonProgramW6432      C:\Program Files\Common Files
COMPUTERNAME            ELSPHIL-7013101
ComSpec                 C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe
GFORTRAN_STDERR_UNIT    -1
GFORTRAN_STDOUT_UNIT    -1
HOME                    \\ELSPHIDATP04VA\COMBSD
HOMEDRIVE               C:
HOMEPATH                \Users\combsd
LOCALAPPDATA            C:\Users\combsd\AppData\Local
LOGONSERVER             \\ELSPHIDCXP021
MSYS2_ENV_CONV_EXCL     R_ARCH
NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS    4
OneDrive                C:\Users\combsd\OneDrive - [Redacted Employer Name]
OneDriveCommercial      C:\Users\combsd\OneDrive - [Redacted Employer Name]
OS                      Windows_NT
PATH                    C:\Rtools\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common
                        Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Rtools\bin;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program
                        Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client
                        SDK\ODBC\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files
                        (x86)\Microsoft SQL
                        Server\140\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program
                        Files\Microsoft SQL
                        Server\140\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program
                        Files\Microsoft SQL
                        Server\140\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files
                        (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\Client
                        SDK\ODBC\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files
                        (x86)\Microsoft SQL
                        Server\140\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files
                        (x86)\Microsoft SQL
                        Server\140\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\;C:\Program
                        Files\EasyFrom Inc\;C:\Program
                        Files\nodejs\;C:\Program
                        Files\Git\cmd;C:\Users\combsd\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\combsd\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX
                        2.9\miktex\bin\x64\;C:\Users\combsd\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Users\combsd\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft
                        VS Code\bin;C:\Program
                        Files\heroku\bin;C:\Users\combsd\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\bin
PATHEXT                 .COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC
PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE
                        x86
PROCESSOR_ARCHITEW6432
                        AMD64
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER    Intel64 Family 6 Model 142 Stepping 9,
                        GenuineIntel
PROCESSOR_LEVEL         6
PROCESSOR_REVISION      8e09
ProgramData             C:\ProgramData
ProgramFiles            C:\Program Files (x86)
ProgramFiles(x86)       C:\Program Files (x86)
ProgramW6432            C:\Program Files
PSModulePath            C:\Program
                        Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules;C:\Program
                        Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL
                        Server\140\Tools\PowerShell\Modules\
PUBLIC                  C:\Users\Public
R_ARCH                  /i386
R_COMPILED_BY           gcc 4.9.3
R_HOME                  C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-35~1.3
R_LIBS_USER             \\ELSPHIDATP04VA\COMBSD/R/win-library/3.5
R_USER                  \\ELSPHIDATP04VA\COMBSD
SESSIONNAME             Console
snow_agent              C:\Program Files\Snow Software\Inventory\Agent
SystemDrive             C:
SystemRoot              C:\WINDOWS
TEMP                    C:\Users\combsd\AppData\Local\Temp
TMP                     C:\Users\combsd\AppData\Local\Temp
UATDATA                 C:\WINDOWS\CCM\UATData\D9F8C395-CAB8-491d-B8AC-179A1FE1BE77
USERDNSDOMAIN           SCIENCE.[Redacted Employer Name].NET
USERDOMAIN              SCIENCE
USERDOMAIN_ROAMINGPROFILE
                        SCIENCE
USERNAME                combsd
USERPROFILE             C:\Users\combsd
windir                  C:\WINDOWS
```

Any support whatsoever is greatly appreciated.  I'm happy to answer questions / provide more information, but I don't know where to turn at this point.

Comment: Are you sharing your VM with multiple other users?  What's your `memory.limit` and `memory.size`

Comment: It looks like your R library is on a server rather than stored locally: `\\ELSPHIDATP04VA\COMBSD/R/win-library/3.5`, could that be slowing you down?

Comment: The fact that rgui.exe takes several minutes to load tidyverse points to this being a problem with how R and your network interact, not RStudio. In particular, see if creating a mapped drive letter for your network share, and using that in R, changes anything.

Comment: @DaveGruenewald I am the only user of my laptop. Running the memory functions returned the following: 
>memory.size() 
[1] 20.23 
>memory.limit() 
[1] 3583
@Marius Given the number of comments suggesting the issue pertains to how R interacts with my company network, I did map my `R_LIBS_USER` to a local path. That seems to be helping, but I've had issues when working remote and using VPN with this solution in the past. I'm going to explore this further, along with the suggestions from @HongOoi and @KevinUshey. I really appreciate all of the support and suggestions for further research.

Answer (score 3):

I think this question would be better received at https://community.rstudio.com/c/rstudio-ide, as Stack Overflow generally doesn't work as well with questions that require extra back-and-forth to discover the root of the problem.

Some possibly relevant threads:

https://community.rstudio.com/t/exceptionally-slow-to-open-rstudio-and-package-manager/20810/2

https://community.rstudio.com/t/rstudio-1-1-383-issue-on-startup/1819/15

And I'd also suggest checking out the [preview release](https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/preview/).

Comment: Thanks Kevin. The reason I didn't post it there is because this is not an RStudio-only issue, as it's also occurring with R, so I wasn't sure if it would be appropriate. I can transfer the conversation there and also further investigate these links.  Really appreciate you sharing.

Comment: Sorry, that's a good point. And if e.g. loading the tidyverse package is taking such a long time, I think the most likely culprit is a slow network connection, since you have your packages on a NFS. I would check to see if things are faster with a local library path (not just re-mapping your network library) to confirm.